# A faster way to copy a postgresql database (or the best way)

Tags: postgresql

I did a pg_dump of a database and am now trying to install the resulting .sql file on to another server.

I'm using the following command.

```
psql -f databasedump.sql
```

I initiated the database install earlier today and now 7 hours later the database is still being populated. I don't know if this his how long it is supposed to take, but I continue to monitor it, so far I've seen over 12 millon inserts and counting. I suspect there's a faster way to do this.

Comment: Either way, 12 million inserts, that's normally a matter of something like a minute on halfway decent hardware, even with psql and a plain SQL dump. If it took 7 hours, then somehthing's not right with your setup.

Comment: This is probably obvious, but check that you did _not_ supply the cross-db compatibility options `--inserts` or `--column-inserts` to the dump. You can also check that your ASCII script uses `COPY` to reload the data.

Comment: For more information, I'm working with an EC2 micro-instance, so it's a bit memory restricted. It's Postgresql 7.4 (had to compile it myself) because the data is from an old 7.4 setup.

Comment: maybe do the restore on faster hardware, do a vacuum full on the database and then do a file copy to the EC2, eg: using rsync.

Comment: I had the same issue (with ASP.Net Core) and I realized my logging was slowing it down tremendously. A US postal code table import took mere seconds.

Answer (score 156):

Create your dumps with

```
pg_dump -Fc -Z 9  --file=file.dump myDb
```

`Fc`

> Output a custom archive suitable for input into pg_restore. This is the most flexible format in that it allows reordering of loading data as well as object definitions. This format is also compressed by default.

`Z 9: --compress=0..9`

> Specify the compression level to use. Zero means no compression. For the custom archive format, this specifies compression of individual table-data segments, and the default is to compress at a moderate level. For plain text output, setting a nonzero compression level causes the entire output file to be compressed, as though it had been fed through gzip; but the default is not to compress. The tar archive format currently does not support compression at all.

and restore it with

```
pg_restore -Fc -j 8  file.dump
```

`-j: --jobs=number-of-jobs`

> Run the most time-consuming parts of pg_restore — those which load data, create indexes, or create constraints — using multiple concurrent jobs. This option can dramatically reduce the time to restore a large database to a server running on a multiprocessor machine.
>
> Each job is one process or one thread, depending on the operating system, and uses a separate connection to the server.
>
> The optimal value for this option depends on the hardware setup of the server, of the client, and of the network. Factors include the number of CPU cores and the disk setup. A good place to start is the number of CPU cores on the server, but values larger than that can also lead to faster restore times in many cases. Of course, values that are too high will lead to decreased performance because of thrashing.
>
> Only the custom and directory archive formats are supported with this option. The input must be a regular file or directory (not, for example, a pipe). This option is ignored when emitting a script rather than connecting directly to a database server. Also, multiple jobs cannot be used together with the option --single-transaction.

Links:

[pg_dump](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html)

[pg_restore](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgrestore.html)

Comment: Sometimes, pg_dump is much faster with compression turned off (`-Z0`). Obviously, the dump is then much bigger. But if you have room and fast disks, it may be the rght tradeoff.

Comment: If you can, using an external compressor is MUCH more performant. `pg_dump ... -Fc -Z0 | pigz > file.dump.gz` is ~3x faster then the built in compression for me, probably because the built in compression is single threaded?

Comment: To add to mikv comment: it's 5 times faster on my SSD even though I go from 45Mo to 5,4Go. Nowadays time is more important than size (lol!).

Comment: The question asks for "faster way", so the answer should not use the largest compression.

Comment: Can it be used with pg_dumpall?

Answer (score 46):

## Improve pg dump&restore

PG_DUMP | always use format directory with `-j` option

```
time pg_dump -j 8 -Fd -f /tmp/newout.dir fsdcm_external
```

PG_RESTORE | always use tuning for postgres.conf with format directory With `-j` option

```
work_mem = 32MB
shared_buffers = 4GB
maintenance_work_mem = 2GB
full_page_writes = off
autovacuum = off
wal_buffers = -1

time pg_restore -j 8 --format=d -C -d postgres /tmp/newout.dir/`
```

For more info

https://gitlab.com/yanar/Tuning/wikis/improve-pg-dump&restore

Comment: Some might think it's weird that in your repo, you are comparing "PG_DUMP 9.6 Fc Format VS Fd Format", but the latter gets an additional -j 8 argument. Maybe worth adding a note that "parallel backup is only supported by the directory format".
Also, it would be nice if you also report resulting file sizes for Fc/Fd comparison.

Answer (score 20):

Why are you producing a raw .sql dump? The opening description of [pg_dump](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/app-pgdump.html) recommends the "custom" format `-Fc`.

Then you can use pg_restore which will restore your data (or selected parts of it). There is  a "number of jobs" option `-j` which can use multiple cores (assuming your disks aren't already the limiting factor). In most cases, on a modern machine you can expect at least some gains from this.

Now you say "I don't know how long this is supposed to take". Well, until you've done a few restores you won't know. Do monitor what your system is doing and whether you are limited by cpu or disk I/O.

Finally, the configuration settings you want for restoring a database are not those you want to run it. A couple of useful starters:

1. Increase [maintenance_work_mem](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/runtime-config-resource.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-RESOURCE-MEMORY) so you can build indexes in larger chunks
2. Turn off [fsync](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/runtime-config-wal.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-WAL-SETTINGS) during the restore. If your machine crashes, you'll start from scratch again anyway.

Do remember to reset them after the restore though.

Comment: This is hugely useful information. I'm obviously clueless about Postgresql even though I've used it in the past. I've found your feedback to be very enlightening.

Comment: It took about 9 hours using psql. I'd like to test this out using pg_restore, should I just run pg_restore or is it better to wipe my data directory and start from scratch (This is a test box, the mission critical data is all on the live box)?

Comment: You'll need a new dump (-Fc), then if you've got the disk space you can restore a database under a different name if you like. Plan to monitor it this time - indexes can easily take longer than the table data. You might well find it useful to create a smaller test db (same structure) and dump/restore that multiple times to get a better feel for how thing interact.

Answer (score 11):

The usage of `pg_dump` is generally recommended to be paired with `pg_restore`, instead of `psql`. This method can be split among cores to speed up the loading process by passing the `--jobs` flag as such:

```
    $ pg_dump -Fc db > db.Fc.dump
    $ pg_restore -d db --jobs=8 db.Fc.dump
```

Postgres themselves have a [guide](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/populate.html) on bulk loading of data.

I also would recommend heavily tuning your `postgresql.conf` configuration file and set appropriately high values for the `maintenance_work_mem` and `checkpoint_segments` values; higher values on these may dramatically increase your write performance.

Comment: please don't post obviously wrong information. If you don't know the answer to a question then don't answer. Your answer is not just not right anyone following it would find their life made more difficult not easier.

Comment: I apologize; I realized after I posted the answer it was quite incorrect. I have updated the answer to the best of my knowledge, but I will simply remove the answer if my understanding and usage of pg_restore is incorrect.

Comment: Your edited answer seems much more useful. I've removed my downvote. I'd remove my comment, but I don't think this chain would make much sense then.

Comment: Understood, and thanks - my mind is so stuck in the world of partitioning and loading data across multiple connections as it comes in that I just kind of blabber-mouthed my first answer. Long day...