# pg_dump/pg_restore lc_collate English_United States.1252 Windows Linux migration

Tags: postgresql

I want to use

```
pg_dump -j 8 -Fd -f /tmp/newout.dir fsdcm_external
```

without dumping LC_COLLATE ('English_United States.1252'), as it is incompatible with my Linux box.

I initially successfully migrated a DB with LC_COLLATE = 'English_United States.1252' with the following procedure:

@Windows machine:

```
pg_dump postgres > "/drive/folder/options.bak"
```

@Linux machine:

```
psql postgres < "/drive/folder/backup.bak"
```

However, I prefer to use "jobs" for parallel dumping and restoring (as in [A faster way to copy a postgresql database (or the best way)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15692508/a-faster-way-to-copy-a-postgresql-database-or-the-best-way)), therefore I tried:

@Windows machine:

```
pg_dump -j 8 -Fd -f /tmp/newout.dir fsdcm_external
```

@Linux machine:

```
pg_restore -j 8 --format=d -C -d postgres /tmp/newout.dir/
```

I expected to have the same LC_COLLATE neutral dump, but instead I received this error:

```
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error while PROCESSING TOC:
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 3498; 1262        
12401 DATABASE postgres postgres
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:                  
invalid locale name: "English_United States.1252"
Command was: CREATE DATABASE postgres WITH TEMPLATE = template0 
ENCODING = 'UTF8' LC_COLLATE = 'English_United States.1252' 
LC_CTYPE = 'E...
```

How do I specify in my pg_dump or pg_restore to refrain from replicating LC_COLLATE settings? Can I only dump the tables, data and indexes for example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is the `-C` option of `pg_restore`.

Instead, first create the database, and then run `pg_restore` without `-C`:

```sh
createdb fsdcm_external
pg_restore -j 8 --format=d -d fsdcm_external /tmp/newout.dir/
```

Answer (score -1):

I spent last 3 hours trying to restore with the PGAdmin GUI but it wouldn't let me. Thank goodness for the command line. Thanks Laurenz.

For anyone else reading, run it in the Terminal (Mac). Not in pysql. You may to need to indicate -U postgres the default user.

pg_restore -U postgres --exit-on-error --verbose --dbname=yourdbname /Users/gc/Downloads/file.tar